# Drawable dimensions different bitmap dimensions in ImageView, is it inScaled?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an image that's a result of decoding from an input stream from a file URI. The extraction code is as follows:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = true;
options.inSampleSize = bitmapSampleSize;

float scaleW = targetWidth/(sourceDims.x/bitmapSampleSize);
float scaleH = targetHeight/(sourceDims.y/bitmapSampleSize);

int initialDensity, targetDensity;
if(scaleW > scaleH)
{
    initialDensity = sourceDims.x;
    targetDensity = targetWidth*bitmapSampleSize;
}
else
{
    initialDensity = sourceDims.y;
    targetDensity = targetHeight * bitmapSampleSize;
}
options.inDensity = initialDensity;
options.inTargetDensity = targetDensity;
is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(pictUri);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
```

When I'm trying to decode a 64x64 image from the resource to make it 400x400, for some reason when I set it in an ImageView, the drawable I get from it returns 640x640 instead.

When I try to decode a 5312x2988 photo from file to make it 1820x1024, the drawable I get from the ImageView is only 786.8x442.5 instead.

Why is this? Is it something to do with inScaled? Is inScaled screen density dependent or something?

EDIT: I don't use `decodeResource()`, and the URI from the resource is as follows:

```
final Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getResources().getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.filter_aomi) + '/' +
            getResources().getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.filter_aomi) + '/' + getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.filter_aomi));
```

Comment: It depends on the ScaleType of your ImageView

Comment: Do I have to change anything if it uses the Matrix scale type?

Comment: `from an input stream from a file URI` and `image from the resource `. That is something completely different. Please explain better what you are doing. BitmapFactory.decodeResource will indeed scale the image to device specific dimensions. And we cannot see how you use uris and resoures. Pretty important to show them.